# How to transform boolean object quicker

Tags: modeling, modifiers, transforms, drivers

H i , i wanted to transform an object ( a cube ) which booleaned in different mode by another object ( an sphere) the way that it moves with out change , i found if i parent the second object to the first one , it will move with the base object but the problem is when i moving the base object , blender calculates the boolean each time which is time consuming , consider that i don't want to apply boolean (stay parametric) , my purpose seems like to be a riddle , but it's not , im creating parametric architectural elements which need to move , and if there is any possible workaround feel free and leave an answer .

Comment: If the boolean should stay dynamic as you assert, you can tray to speed things up by simplifying the two objects that are booleaning. Maybe if you can share a image, a blend file, other ideas can come up... Anyway, when you render the movie, the speed should be correct.

Comment: did you try the boolean "fast" button? speeds up a lot in my test...

Comment: @Chris guys very thanks for your helps , but this  is more like a generic question , the fact that a booleaned object doesn't need to be calculated each time we transform it in new location idk should i post this on rightclick select maybe ?

Comment: Maybe open a feature/improvement request for Blender

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could move the objects being boolean'd into a new collection, leaving the boolean objects in another collection. Then go to Add>Collection Instance>[collection name]. The collection instance can be moved without lag whilst still being editable by editing the original.

These objects consist of half a million vertices with no lag.

[image]
[image]

Comment: woah! didn't expected someone to find the answer , but i didn't quite understand it , maybe because of my lack of knowledge ,